# How do I merge into one sublist the two sublists with the same index 0?

Tags: python, list

It's not the same as flattening a list.

I have this list of lists:

```
listoflists = [[853, 'na'], [854, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], [854, [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

I want those sublists which have the same index 0 (in this case 854) to be combined but not flattened, like so:

```
listoflists_v2 = [[853, 'na'], [854, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8]]]
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Is the order important, so is it important that `listoflists_v2 = [[853, 'na'], [854, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8]]]` is returned and not `listoflists_v2 = [[853, 'na'], [854, [2, 4, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]]`?

Comment: @quant no it is not.

Comment: Do the keys are always consecutives?

Comment: @DanielMesejo if by key you mean each index 0, then yes. it's ordered and looks like that

Comment: I see but each index 0 can appear anywhere or are the groups consecutive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order is important, use an `OrderedDict` and collect values per key:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
for k, v in listoflists:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

listoflists_v2 = [[k, *v] for k, v in d.items()]
```

If not, use a `defaultdict`, you get slightly better performance:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in listoflists:
   d[k].append(v)

listoflists_v2 = [[k, *v] for k, v in d.items()]
```

Another option is using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
listoflists.sort(key=itemgetter(0)) # Do this if keys aren't consecutive.

listoflists_v2 = [
    [k, *map(itemgetter(1), g)] 
    for k, g in groupby(listoflists, key=itemgetter(0))
]
```

---

```
print(listoflists_v2)
[[853, 'na'], [854, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6, 8]]]
```

Comment: why does it say invalid syntax on the line d = defaultdict(list)?

Comment: @sneedshelp Check the line above in your code please. I typed this out on an interpreter before pasting it here.

Comment: I like the itertools method. that worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of going about it although i wouldn't recommend it. Its good
for learning i guess.

```
# orginal list
listoflists = [[853, 'na'], [854, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], [854, [2, 4, 6, 8]]]
# new list with combined data
new_list = []

# loop through all sublists
for sub_list in listoflists:
    # check if new_list is empty to see if its data should be compared
    # with the orinal if not add sublist to new_list
    if new_list:
        # check all the lists in new_list
        for list_ in new_list:
            # if the list in new_list and one of the original lists
            # first element match, add the values of the original list
            # starting from the first elemnt to the new_list
            if sub_list[0] == list_[0]:
                list_.append(sub_list[1:])

            else:
                list_.append(sub_list)

    else:
        new_list.append(sub_list)

print(new_list)
```